# Proper way to create and work with a subdomain?

Tags: seo, subdomain, pagerank, ranking, google-panda-algorithm

My site got effected by Panda, and I am trying to see if making a subdomain would work.

The site is comehike.com, and I created a subdomain which is currently empty at hiking.comehike.com

I have a directory `/outdoors` that has some high quality hand-written articles.  I want to put those into the new subdomain to see what would happen.

My questions are:

1. Should I just copy and paste the files for those pages into the new subdomain's folder, and just change all the links in all my pages from the original domain to the new subdomain?
2. Should I just do a 301 redirect to the new subdomain?
3. Since `test.site.com` and `www.site.com` are different domains, will the new page have to start from scratch in terms of Pagerank, and its rankings in the SERPs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Copy and paste the files for the pages with the articles into the new subdomain's folder **and** 301 redirect from the old pages.

2) See above.

3) Essentially yes, each page has it's own PR value - for example whilst facebook.com might be a PR 9/10 site, my profile on facebook is probably not even PR 1. Though if you're homepage has a PR, you can pass 'link juice' to your new subdomain by linking to the pages directly from it.

Didn't want to get too in-depth, but think I gave you enough to go on. :)